# Are breakout boards a bad idea to use with high speed/performance ICs?

Tags: pcb, rf, fpga, adc

I am interested in using the [DAC908E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac908.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1629791125646&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F) to convert an FPGA DDS generated sine wave (~6 MHz) into analog form and then feed the same analog sine wave back into the FPGA through an ADC (with equal sampling speed).

When examining the documentation for DAC908E, I notice a lot of external circuitry included to optimize performance.

Because I only need a DAC and ADC, I'm not interested in all the added functionality of evaluation boards or their increased cost. My original solution was simply to buy breakout boards that matched the IC package of the DAC or ADC and then simply solder connections. This leads me to my question:

**Generally speaking, are breakout boards a bad idea to use at high frequencies and/or when signal integrity is essential?**

and,

**Is my approach of IC -> breakout board -> solder to wires/connectors -> FPGA/microcontroller a bad idea?**

I'd prefer to not have to design my own PCB unless I absolutely must.

Comment: Do you mean breakout boards as in the products from Sparkfun/Adafruit that include the decoupling capacitors, or a generic breakout with just the footprint?

Comment: I was going to buy one with just the footprint. Do you think the Sparkfun/Adafruit ones are sufficient? I don't see anything special about those. I think the decoupling is probably only on specific packages. The DAC908E for example is TSSOP-28 and I don't see any breakout boards with nice decoupling

Comment: In your other question you seemed concerned with having a very accurate output from this device at high frequency.  That is absolutely not going to happen without a well designed PCB.

Comment: Yeah, I figured but I was also curious to hear people’s opinions on these in general. I didn’t know they existed until about a month ago. Also my previous question was rather dumb once I understood the answer. Don’t know why it got voted up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal breakout boards usually don't have footprints for the decoupling caps the specific chip needs, so you will have to bodge it somewhere on the 0.1" headers, and you will get power integrity problems.

But the main problem is not the breakout board... it's connecting it to the FPGA board with wires and sending high speed digital signals in the wires. This tends not to work, if signal integrity is bad enough you get ringing, double clocking etc. And if it does work, it will be very noisy and the analog performance of your DAC-ADC will suck.

You will get much better results with a cheap double sided PCB from jlcpcb or other shops that do 5 bucks pcbs. Just put a continuous ground plane on the back, put the decoupling caps near the chip, and route your signals over that ground plane, and connect to FPGA board with appropriate headers. You will get much lower noise and crosstalk if each digital line is coupled to the ground plane under it.

If you don't want to spend time doing a complete layout, you can just place the two chips on the board with decoupling caps, quickly route all the signals that can be routed, and if some signals would need lots of vias and cause a headache, just use a wire instead... but put the wire on the ground plane side of the board, and tape it on top of the ground plane. That works just like a trace over a ground plane, it is quick to do, and you get no noise problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a decent sample rate, your frequencies are definitely in the territory where signal quality matters, and trace length skew starts to matter.

Given that it's a simple application that can probably be routed on a two layer board, I'd expect designing your own PCB will be both faster and cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I have often used solid copper boards to operate 928 MHz with drill holes for insulated short wires.  If you look around for such test jigs, you will see how it's done.  Low ESL and high stray C to ground plane yields low L/C = Z\$^2\$ and using twisted AWG 30 magnet wire pairs is another way.